# BLE ESP32 connection problems: "assert failed: heap_caps_free heap_caps.c:360 (heap != NULL && "free() target pointer is outside heap areas")"

Tags: c, automation, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-ide

I have a mi Smart Cube from Xiaomi, and I am having problems when connecting the cube to ESP32 (code function is only LED with the movement of the cube, I took video on YouTube to learn)

**Full serial print:**

```
rst:0x1 (POWERON_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13220
ho 0 tail 12 room 4
load:0x40080400,len:3028
entry 0x400805e4
Initialising BLE...Done.
Scanning for Bluetooth devices...
 - 32:6f:94:84:d2:84... MAC address does not match
 - 01:3b:d8:c9:c7:0f... MAC address does not match
 - 1f:2b:18:45:1f:2e... MAC address does not match
 - 2d:ef:0f:f1:e6:9e... MAC address does not match
 - 34:c4:c4:fc:ce:60... MAC address does not match
 - 16:72:4e:de:94:a1... MAC address does not match
 - 47:47:90:80:57:76... MAC address does not match
 - e7:ef:5d:a5:be:14... MAC address does not match
 - da:39:3f:f1:52:e4... MAC address does not match
 - d5:da:2d:c4:33:e9 - Connecting!
Creating BLE client... Done.
Assigning callbacks...  - Done.
Connecting to d5:da:2d:c4:33:e9...  - Done.
Finding service 0000aadb-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb...  - Done.
Finding characteristic 0000aadc-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb...  - Done.
Registering for notifications... Current State: 0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x33,0x33,0x33,0x33,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x9A,0xBC,0x0,0x0,
Last Move: Front Face Anti-Clockwise
----
 - Done.
READY!

assert failed: heap_caps_free heap_caps.c:360 (heap != NULL && "free() target pointer is outside heap areas")


Backtrace: 0x40083675:0x3ffc92b0 0x400928a1:0x3ffc92d0 0x40098075:0x3ffc92f0 0x40083a0e:0x3ffc9420 0x400980a5:0x3ffc9440 0x4017b155:0x3ffc9460 0x4017b684:0x3ffc9480 0x400d227e:0x3ffc94a0 0x400d272a:0x3ffc94f0 0x400d7d85:0x3ffc9510




ELF file SHA256: 785753016bac645b

Rebooting...
ets Jun  8 2016 00:22:57
```

**Full Code:**

```
/**
 * ESP32-SmartCube
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Playful Technology
 * 
 * ESP32 sketch to connect to Xiaomi "Smart Magic Cube" Rubik's Cube via Bluetooth LE
 * and decode notification messages containing puzzle state.
 * Prints output to serial connection of the last move made, and when the cube is fully
 * solved, triggers a relay output
 */

// INCLUDES
// ESP32 library for Bluetooth LE
#include "BLEDevice.h"

// CONSTANTS
// The MAC address of the Rubik's Cube
// This can be discovered by starting a scan BEFORE touching the cube. Then twist any face
// to wake the cube up and see what new device appears
static BLEAddress *pServerAddress = new BLEAddress("d5:da:2d:c4:33:e9");
// The remote service we wish to connect to
static BLEUUID serviceUUID("0000aadb-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
// The characteristic of the remote service we want to track
static BLEUUID charUUID("0000aadc-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
// The following constants are used to decrypt the data representing the state of the cube
// see https://github.com/cs0x7f/cstimer/blob/master/src/js/bluetooth.js
const uint8_t decryptionKey[] = {176, 81, 104, 224, 86, 137, 237, 119, 38, 26, 193, 161, 210, 126, 150, 81, 93, 13, 236, 249, 89, 235, 88, 24, 113, 81, 214, 131, 130, 199, 2, 169, 39, 165, 171, 41};
// This pin will have a HIGH pulse sent when the cube is solved
int ledAmarelo = 33;
int ledVerde = 32;
int ledAzul = 25;
int ledVermelho = 26;

// This is the data array representing a solved cube
const byte solution[16] = {0x12,0x37,0x86,0x45,0x13,0x33,0x21,0x33,0xB2,0x34,0x96,0x78,0xAC,0x15,0x08,0x10};
const byte Amarelo[16] = {0x12,0x37,0x45,0x86,0x13,0x33,0x33,0x21,0xB2,0x34,0x96,0x78,0x15,0xAC,0x08,0x40};
const byte Verde[16] = {0x81,0x37,0x62,0x45,0x23,0x33,0x31,0x33,0xB9,0x34,0xC2,0x78,0xA6,0x15,0x40,0x10};
const byte Azul[16] = {0x12,0x43,0x86,0x57,0x13,0x11,0x21,0x11,0xB2,0x37,0x96,0x54,0xAC,0x18,0x0A,0x00};
const byte Vermelho[16] = {0x12,0x37,0x58,0x64,0x13,0x33,0x31,0x23,0xB2,0x34,0x96,0x78,0x5A,0xC1,0x08,0x80};
const byte Laranja[16] = {0x12,0x37,0x64,0x58,0x13,0x33,0x23,0x31,0xB2,0x34,0x96,0x78,0xC1,0x5A,0x08,0x20};

// GLOBALS
// Have we found a cube with the right MAC address to connect to?
static boolean deviceFound = false;
// Are we currently connected to the cube?
static boolean connected = false;
// Properties of the device found via scan
static BLEAdvertisedDevice* myDevice;
// BT characteristic of the connected device
static BLERemoteCharacteristic* pRemoteCharacteristic;

// HELPER FUNCTIONS
/**
 * Return the ith bit from an integer array
 */
int getBit(uint8_t* val, int i) {
  int n = ((i / 8) | 0);
  int shift = 7 - (i % 8);
  return (val[n] >> shift) & 1;    
}

/**
 * Return the ith nibble (half-byte, i.e. 16 possible values)
 */
uint8_t getNibble(uint8_t val[], int i) {
  if(i % 2 == 1) {
    return val[(i/2)|0] % 16;
  }
  return 0|(val[(i/2)|0] / 16);
}

// CALLBACKS
/**
 * Callbacks for devices found via a Bluetooth scan of advertised devices
 */
class AdvertisedDeviceCallbacks: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks {
  // The onResult callback is called for every advertised device found by the scan  
  void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
    // Print the MAC address of this device
    Serial.print(" - ");
    Serial.print(advertisedDevice.getAddress().toString().c_str());
    // Does this device match the MAC address we're looking for?
    if(advertisedDevice.getAddress().equals(*pServerAddress)) {
      // Stop scanning for further devices
      advertisedDevice.getScan()->stop();
      // Create a new device based on properties of advertised device
      myDevice = new BLEAdvertisedDevice(advertisedDevice);
      // Set flag
      deviceFound = true;
      Serial.println(F(" - Connecting!"));
    }
    else {
      Serial.println(F("... MAC address does not match"));
    }
  }
};

/**
 * Callbacks for device we connect to
 */
class ClientCallbacks : public BLEClientCallbacks {
  // Called when a new connection is established
  void onConnect(BLEClient* pclient) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
    connected = true;
  }
  // Called when a connection is lost
  void onDisconnect(BLEClient* pclient) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
    connected = false;
  }
};

/**
 * Called whenever a notication is received that the tracked BLE characterisic has changed
 */
static void notifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic, uint8_t* pData, size_t length, bool isNotify) {
  // DECRYPT DATA
  // Early Bluetooth cubes used an unencrypted data format that sent the corner/edge indexes as a 
  // simple raw string, e.g. pData for a solved cube would be 1234567833333333123456789abc000041414141
  // However, newer cubes e.g. Giiker i3s encrypt data with a rotating key, so that same state might be
  // 706f6936b1edd1b5e00264d099a4e8a19d3ea7f1 then d9f67772c3e9a5ea6e84447abb527156f9dca705 etc.
  
  // To find out whether the data is encrypted, we first read the penultimate byte of the characteristic data. 
  // As in the two examples above, if this is 0xA7, we know it's encrypted
  bool isEncrypted = (pData[18] == 0xA7);

  // If it *is* encrypted...
  if(isEncrypted) {
    // Split the last byte into two 4-bit values 
    int offset1 = getNibble(pData, 38);
    int offset2 = getNibble(pData, 39);

    // Retrieve a pair of offset values from the decryption key 
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
      // Apply the offset to each value in the data
      pData[i] += (decryptionKey[offset1 + i] + decryptionKey[offset2 + i]);
    }
  }

  // First 16 bytes represent state of the cube - 8 corners (with 3 orientations), and 12 edges (can be flipped)
  Serial.print("Current State: ");
    for (int i=0; i<16; i++) {
      Serial.print("0x");
      Serial.print(pData[i], HEX);
      Serial.print(",");
    }
  Serial.println("");

  // Byte 17 represents the last twist made - first half-byte is face, and second half-byte is direction of rotation
  int lastMoveFace = getNibble(pData, 32);
  int lastMoveDirection = getNibble(pData, 33);
  char* faceNames[6] = {"Front", "Bottom", "Right", "Top", "Left", "Back"};
  Serial.print("Last Move: ");
  Serial.print(faceNames[lastMoveFace-1]);
  Serial.print(lastMoveDirection == 1 ? " Face Clockwise" : " Face Anti-Clockwise" );
  Serial.println("");
  
  Serial.println("----");

  if(memcmp(pData, solution, 16) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledVerde, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledAzul, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledVermelho, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledVerde, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledAzul, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledVermelho, LOW);
  }
  if(memcmp(pData, Amarelo, 16) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, LOW);
  }
   if(memcmp(pData, Verde, 16) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledVerde, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledVerde, LOW);
  }
    if(memcmp(pData, Azul, 16) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledAzul, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledAzul, LOW);
  }
   if(memcmp(pData, Vermelho, 16) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledVermelho, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledVermelho, LOW);
  }
     if(memcmp(pData, Laranja, 16) == 0) {
    digitalWrite(ledVermelho, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, HIGH);
    delay(500);
    digitalWrite(ledVermelho, LOW);
    digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, LOW);
  }
}

/*
 * Connect to the BLE server of the correct MAC address
 */
bool connectToServer() {
    Serial.print(F("Creating BLE client... "));
    BLEClient* pClient = BLEDevice::createClient();
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(F("Done."));

    Serial.print(F("Assigning callbacks... "));
    pClient->setClientCallbacks(new ClientCallbacks());
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(F(" - Done."));

    // Connect to the remove BLE Server.
    Serial.print(F("Connecting to "));
    Serial.print(myDevice->getAddress().toString().c_str());
    Serial.print(F("... "));
    pClient->connect(myDevice);
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(" - Done.");
    
    // Obtain a reference to the service we are after in the remote BLE server.
    Serial.print(F("Finding service "));
    Serial.print(serviceUUID.toString().c_str());
    Serial.print(F("... "));
    BLERemoteService* pRemoteService = pClient->getService(serviceUUID);
    delay(500);
    if (pRemoteService == nullptr) {
      Serial.println(F("FAILED."));
      return false;
    }
    Serial.println(" - Done.");
    delay(500);

    // Obtain a reference to the characteristic in the service of the remote BLE server.
    Serial.print(F("Finding characteristic "));
    Serial.print(charUUID.toString().c_str());
    Serial.print(F("... "));
    pRemoteCharacteristic = pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(charUUID);
    if (pRemoteCharacteristic == nullptr) {
      Serial.println(F("FAILED."));
      return false;
    }
    Serial.println(" - Done.");
    delay(500);
    
    Serial.print(F("Registering for notifications... "));
    if(pRemoteCharacteristic->canNotify()) {
      pRemoteCharacteristic->registerForNotify(notifyCallback);
      Serial.println(" - Done.");
    }
    else {
      Serial.println(F("FAILED."));
      return false;
    }

    Serial.println("READY!");
}

/**
 * Search for any advertised devices
 */
void scanForDevices(){
  Serial.println("Scanning for Bluetooth devices...");
  // Retrieve a Scanner and set the callback we want to use to be informed when we
  // have detected a new device.  Specify that we want active scanning and start the
  // scan to run for 30 seconds.
  BLEScan* pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan();
  pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new AdvertisedDeviceCallbacks());
  pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true);
  pBLEScan->start(30);
}

// Initial setup
void setup() {
  // Start the serial connection to be able to track debug data
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.print("Initialising BLE...");
  BLEDevice::init("");
  delay(500);
  Serial.println(F("Done."));

  // ledAmarelo will be set HIGH when the cube is solved
  pinMode(ledAmarelo, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledAzul, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledVerde, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledVermelho, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledAmarelo, LOW);

  // ledPin will be set HIGH when cube is connected 
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

// Main program loop function
void loop() {
  // If the cube has been found, connect to it
  if (deviceFound) {
    if(!connected) {
      connectToServer();
    }
  }
  else {
    scanForDevices();
  }
  // Introduce a little delay
  delay(1000);
}
```

The question is, I tested the same code on three different pcs, for some reason, my teacher's PC worked (Arduino 1.8.19), it connects and reads the movements without problems, my own PC and another PC I tested generated This error at the time it connects and starts reading the movements (2.0.4 and 1.8.5 respectively):

"assert failed: heap_caps_free heap_caps.c:360 (heap != NULL && "free() target pointer is outside heap areas") Backtrace: 0x40083675:0x3ffc92b0 0x400928a1:0x3ffc92d0 0x40098075:0x3ffc92f0 0x40083a0e:0x3ffc9420 0x400980a5:0x3ffc9440 0x4017b155:0x3ffc9460 0x4017b684:0x3ffc9480 0x400d227e:0x3ffc94a0 0x400d272a:0x3ffc94f0 0x400d7d85:0x3ffc9510".

After that he gives a reboot and tries to connect again, generating the same error.

Infos:

- Windows 10
- Arduino IDE (2.0.4 no meu pc)
- ESP32

The expected (and that was achieved on the other PC), was to start the Ble, connect with the cube and it record the movements of the cube:

example:

```
Current State: 0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x33,0x33,0x33,0x33,0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78,0x9A,0xBC,0x0,0x0,
Last Move: Right Face Anti-Clockwise
```

But in other PCs, when you will start reading, it generates this error:

```
assert failed: heap_caps_free heap_caps.c:360 (heap != NULL && "free() target pointer is outside heap areas")


Backtrace: 0x40083675:0x3ffc92b0 0x400928a1:0x3ffc92d0 0x40098075:0x3ffc92f0 0x40083a0e:0x3ffc9420 0x400980a5:0x3ffc9440 0x4017b571:0x3ffc9460 0x4017b884:0x3ffc9480 0x400d227e:0x3ffc94a0 0x400d272a:0x3ffc94f0 0x400d8591:0x3ffc9510
```

After generating the error it makes a reboot and tries to connect again, generating the same error when starting reading

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have solved it installing an older version of Espressif Drivers. With 1.0.6 it worked.